# Difference between cellular modems and modems used in wifi router

Tags: digital-communications

Can someone explain the difference between 5G Cellular modems used in our Mobile phones to that of modems used in the wifi router?

TIA

Comment: one does whatever is needed to mo/dem 5G signals and the other one does whatever is needed to mo/dem Wi-Fi signals. Since they are different signals designed by different people for different purposes I'm sure there is quite a lot of difference between them.

Answer (score 2):

I will start my saying that most of my experience in this area is in cellular PHY, not WiFi. So if I get something wrong about the WiFi side of the comparison, I am open to corrections.

I am also trying to keep this answer short and simple, and it is possible that in simplifying it, it may be "glossing over" some corner cases, but what follows is generally true in current systems (Spring 2023).

#### First, what is the same or similar?

The basic modulation type, OFDM, is the same in 4G/5G and more recent WiFi standards. Other signal processing aspects of the PHY, like MIMO techniques, or the various "modulation and coding schemes" (MCS) are also the same in concept and similar or the same in practice.

Cellular protocols since 3G have used HARQ, a kind of PHY-level ack/rtx based on incremental redundancy. HARQ is coming into use in WiFi, soon, if not already.

#### What is different?

##### In the PHY

The biggest difference in the PHY between WiFi and cellular is that in cellular the basestation has total control. Other than the initial random access procedure ("RACH"), client devices (handsets, modems, etc.) do not transmit or receive data transmissions unless ordered to do so by the basestation. All radio bandwidth allocations, in both directions, are completely controlled by the basestation.

This approach has several advantages over WiFI. It makes more efficient use of the radio channel, by a factor of 2x to 4x. It avoids the hidden node problem and near-far problems. It offers better security, since the PHY layer does not have access to the radio transmissions of other users. (There is no such thing as promiscuous mode in a normal cellular baseband modem, because standard PHY does not support it.)

The cellular PHY also has different timing parameters from WiFi, as it is designed to operate over ranges of tens of kilometers, not just tens of meters.

##### In the MAC

Cellular radio interfaces provide QoS parameters, like guaranteed latency, bandwidth, or packet loss, that are specified by the core network and implemented in the MAC.

##### In the higher layers

Unlike a WiFi access point, the cellular basestation is not a router and does not connect devices directly to the Internet. Cellular connections above the MAC layer "tunnel" through the basestations into the core network where they are connected to the Internet, or to a private IP network, or to some other network type, depending on the requirements of the connection. For example, your normal application-layer data service may connect to the Internet with an IPv6 address, while your VoLTE call may connect to a private IPv4 network for IMS. (This functionality is visible in the settings of a typical handset as a list of access points names, APNs, for the different connection types.)

A handset or modem can have multiple active connections on different APNs, each with a different IP address (or even a different, non-IP, transport layer), different routing rules, and a different set of QoS parameters.

Comment: Nice answer! Welcome to DSP.SE and thanks for finding a way to answer such a broad question with practical insights.